# 3D effect button issue in FF

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style an html form, and mostly it looks great, but some of the fields in the form have this 3-d type button on which you press and it looks like its being pushed down. IE and Chrome work like a charm but FF some how pushes other fields in the form down. Can somebody explain to me what is going on there?

Here is my html markup:

```
 <form action="">
      <label for="name">Name: </label>
      <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name"/>
      <img class="searchGlass" src="searchGlass.jpg" alt="search glass">
      <label for="email">Email: </label>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email"/>
      <label for="phone">Phone: </label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" value="" id="phone"/>
      <label for="message">Message: </label>
      <textarea type="text" name="message" value="" id="message" rows="10" cols="10"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
```

And here are my styles:

```
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <style>
      label {
           display: block;
           font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
           font-size: 13px;
           color: #4d5357;               
      }

      input[type=text], textarea {
           width: 452px;
           height: 20px;
           border: 1px solid #a6a9ab;
           color: #4d5357;
           font-size: 13px;
           padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
           font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      }
      textarea {
           height: 212px;
      }
      img.searchGlass {
           position: relative;
           top: 8px;
           left: -35px;
           border: 1px solid #a6a9ab;
           border-bottom: 3px solid #a6a9ab;
      }
      img.searchGlass:active {
           position: relative;
           top: 8px;
           left: -35px;
           border: 1px solid #a6a9ab;
           border-bottom: none;
           margin-top: 3px;
      }

 </style>
```

Comment: i am not able to recreate what you descriped. 

http://jsfiddle.net/lahmf/4hhrt/1/ .

Same behaviour in chrome and in ff. IE not tested

Comment: Please provide a working sample so that we can find the mistake.

Comment: Works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/2hamed/9P69g/1/

Comment: @HamedMomeni i figgured out what he meant. in firefox when you push on the picture, some of the textboxes drop aswell a little bit

Comment: Is there any good workaround?

Comment: @rustamissabekov look my answer, ive given you a working fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually occurs in all browsers, if you resize them down (*decrease width. You most likely have your browsers in different sizes and because some are wider the problem does not show*).

The problem is that you assume that your image is in the same line as the input field. It only happens to be in the same line if there is enough room. If the width does not suffice it will wrap to the next line.

The solution is to put a wrapper element around the input element and the image that is `position:relative` and put the image at the correct place with `position:absolute` ..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/q93sC/

---

Posting the code changes to avoid confusion from the jsfiddle..

**CSS**

```
 img.searchGlass {
       position: absolute; /*changed this to absolute*/
       top: 4px;
       right: 5px;
       border: 1px solid #a6a9ab;
       border-bottom: 3px solid #a6a9ab;
 }
 img.searchGlass:active { /*simplified this rule as only changed properties need to be defined*/
       border-bottom: none;
       margin-top: 3px;
 }
 .with-icon{ /*Added this rule*/
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
  }
```

and **HTML** (*wrapped `input` and `img` in a `div` with class `with-icon`*)

```
<div class="with-icon">
     <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name"/>
    <img class="searchGlass" src="http://lorempixel.com/20/20/abstract/5" alt="search glass" />
</div>
```

Comment: I think that there is enough space there to on every line to fit input element and img, all browsers were full screen and form element is not restricted with width parameter

Comment: Can you post the dimensions of the `img` as that affects the layout.. Also I just posted a demo of the solution i propose to see it in action..

Comment: The image has a width of 26px and height of 22px, Sir can you pls elaborate why this div made child input element stay in place? Where does this margin comes from, i mean the one which pushes the input element when I press the image?

Comment: Well I understood, why you workaround works. But still struggling to understand why the original problem happened, by the way thanks for your help

Comment: @RustamIssabekov for the `div` i have used i have also created a CSS rule at the end of the CSS `.with-icon{position:relative;display:inline-block;}` This is what keeps the image with `position:absolute` relative to the container..

Comment: @RustamIssabekova updated answer with changes i made to your code so that it works..

Answer (score 0):

There you go works fine for me now. The trick is to give the image an absolute Position and not relative, else the image will be displayed somewhere else, when you click on it and pop the effect

```
    img.searchGlass {
       position: absolute;
       top: 8px;
       left: 480px;
       border: 1px solid #a6a9ab;
       border-bottom: 3px solid #a6a9ab;
  }
  img.searchGlass:active {
       position: absolute;
       top: 8px;
       left: 480px;
       border: 1px solid #a6a9ab;
       border-bottom: none;
       margin-top: 3px;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lahmf/4hhrt/3/